# What is exact value of lastUpdateTime?

Tags: android, installation, updates

Here is quote:

- [`lastUpdateTime`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#lastUpdateTime): *The time at which the app was last updated…*

My question is: Does that value mean the time that *the app got updated on user's device* or *the update-version was published to the market*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> > lastUpdateTime: The time at which the app was last updated…

*this means the time when package installed on Device updated..*

Everytime the apk is installed or updated, the PackageInfo.lastUpdateTime will be update by reading device current System Time.